# What is right way to authenticate a client service when we are using OAuth google Firebase to identify people making REST service to my microservices

Tags: api, oauth

I am identifying Google OAuth firebase library to authenticate valid users who are calling my microservice. I need same mechanism to identify clients which happen to be not people but other trusted services. How can I provide identity to such client services? I know that creating a token which has signature of client would be appropriate way(by using private key at client service side) which can be verified using public key available at my micro service. Please suggest.